# What is the relation between surcharge and fee?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to establish some relationship between fees and surcharges.

Is either of the following correct?

1. All fees are a surcharge
2. All surcharges are a fee

I researched several times online but could not find a clear answer - only specific examples.

The closest I could find is

> A surcharge is an extra fee, charge, or tax that is added on to the cost of a good or service,

From this sentence it looks like a surcharge includes fees, charges and tax. Which means all fees are surcharges but not all surcharges are fees (for example extra tax)

But then I also find:

> Surcharges are fees that a retailer adds to the cost of a purchase

From this sentence is sounds like "all surcharges are fees" - but that clashes if the sentence above. Are tax also fees in that case?

---

I lean towards the following (but don't know if I am correct)

1. The word "Fee" is a synonym to "premium" - which is cost of service.
2. Any fee beyond the cost of the service is an "extra fee".
3. All "extra fees" are surcharges.
4. Not all surcharges are "extra fees".

So when you read an article about convenience fee - that does not necessarily mean we are talking about a surcharge - as it might not be "extra fee" but simply "fee".

The question which fee is extra and which is not depends on each case. (and should be addressed to a finance or billing expert in your field)

Comment: What did you research discover?

Comment: @tchrist added research details to the question.

Comment: Done, and thanks. You might also want to poke around at [money.se]. In some jurisdictions the precise meanings of all these terms, including also service fee vs convenience fee, is established by law or state regulation. In other cases, it comes down to the nature of the merchant's agreement with the payment processor, which varies tremendously according to the enterprise.

Comment: In layman’s English, a *surcharge* is something paid in addition to the *charge*. But as tchrist notes, business, commercial and legal usage can be specialised.

Comment: It's wrong to assume words can be grouped into a hierarchical structure so *fee* is a subset of *surcharge* or vice versa; that's not how language works. Which word is used will depend on existing usage, resemblances, and practices within certain fields (e.g. accountancy and bookkeeping, tourism, and individual trades such as taxi driver or beautician), and it's unlikely to be entirely consistent. What one profession calls a fee another may call a surcharge.

Answer (score 1):

The two concepts do not belong to the same hierarchy; they are overlapping. Calling something a fee usually implies that it is charged for a service, as opposed to goods. Calling something a *surcharge* implies that it is added to some other charge.

If a merchant sells some goods at a such-and-such price, and then charges some additional amount for 'handling', that additional charge is both a surcharge (it is on top of the price of the goods) and a fee (it is charged for the service of handling rather than the goods themselves). But if a seller of goods charges an additional amount for incorporating some special component into the goods themselves, that amount could be called a surcharge, but it wouldn't be natural to call it a fee. On the other hand, professionals charge fees for their services, without these fees being a surcharge on anything.

The term *premium* is usually used only in the context of insurance. The term *convenience fee* does not have a standard meaning; it has been introduced recently in an apparent attempt to make the practice of imposing such surcharges palatable to the consumers.

(As has been pointed out in the comments, in some contexts, both *fee* and *surcharge* may function as technical terms; this answer is does not try to capture the meanings that they may have in such contexts.)